# Why does fprintf uses so much memory on valgrind on bytes allocated?

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I'm trying to understand why my valgrind reports that i use 8.664 bytes when i do a simple fprintf on a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    FILE* creation = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(creation, "something");
    fclose(creation);
}
```

The valgrind reports:

```
==3947== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3947==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3947==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 8,664 bytes allocated
```

Why does this happen ?

Comment: It is a very complex function, having its own buffers etc etc.  8k is nothing on modern compilers.

Comment: Is the memory-consuming function really `fprintf()`? What happens when you remove the `fprintf()` line?

Comment: If I comment `fprintf()` line, the usage drops to 472 (size of a FILE*)

Comment: Add `setvbuf(creation, 0, _IONBF, 0);` in between the fopen and the fprintf, what happens?

Comment: @zwol It drops to 472 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C library appears to delay allocation of the output buffer associated with a FILE object until the first time the FILE is actually written to, or until you use `setvbuf` to configure the buffering. The setvbuf call I suggested in the comments *disables* buffering, in which case the second allocation doesn't happen at all.

8664 - 472 = 8192, or 8 kilobytes, is a reasonable default size for a FILE's output buffer. (For maximum I/O efficiency it needs to be a multiple of 4096, the typical VM page and disk block size.) You can adjust the size, if you want, with other calls to setvbuf; consult its documentation for details.

Answer (score 2):

This is an implementation detail of glibc on your system.

As it frees everything it allocates, it's nothing you need to worry about.

Comment: It is rather a comment, I think.

Comment: One thing i find interesting, is that if I try to run valgrind on the same file, but in different folders, the memory usage is different.
If i copy this file to Desktop area and run valgrind, it uses 4.568 bytes.

Comment: @0___________ I think it answers the question rather well.